# How to understand the SPI clock modes?

Tags: spi

There are many links on the web describing the SPI timing/clock modes. E.g., the following picture from [here](http://www.rosseeld.be/DRO/PIC/SPI_Edges.jpg) indicates 4 combinations of CPOL/CPHA determines when to sampling/transmitting data wrt clock rising/failing edges:

[image]

And for SPI to work correctly, it's required that both the controller(or master) and the device (or slave) should work in the same clock mode.

Few days ago, I encounter a datasheet which describes a QSPI controller, saying that it only supports mode 1 (CPOL=0, CPHA=1). It also containing a AC timing requirement for the SPI interface, as below:

[image]

The timing diagram confirms that the controller works in mode 1: sclk at low when idle, and data sampled at falling edge of sclk.  So far so good.

What puzzled me is another statement in the user guide: "The SPI only supports  SPI mode 1. but, if the SPI device follows the Soc AC timing, it is usable regardless of the mode." How it's possible? Apparently it violates the "same mode" rule. For example, how it works when the controller is in mode 1 (sampling on falling edge) and the device is in mode 0 or 3 (sampling on the rising edge)? In this case, the controller is sampling on the falling edge, implying that the controller starts transmitting a bit on the rising edge. suppose that the width of the bit is one SCLK, and there is no delay of SCLK. then when the device samples the bit (also at the rising edge), it seems that there is no enough setup time (although the hold time is about the entire CLK cycle).

Btw, a working system shows that the controller actually works with a QSPI flash devices whose datasheet tells that it only support mode 0 and 3. This implies that I must miss some points in understanding the SPI clock modes.

It could be possible that the device (and controller) is sampling incoming bits using a faster clock than SCLK (SCLK*4, e.g.), and the bit is sample multiple times. In this case, it may possible to correctly sample the bit after the first sampling, but apparently the time to start the sampling is at the begining of the bit, not at the middle of the bit. I guess this is not an optimal configuration, but I am not sure...

Any explanation is appreciated.

PS: I did a simple experiment on a platform which contains a Cadence QSPI controller and a ISSI flash device. The device datasheet tells that it only support mode 0 (0,0) and 3 (1,1). I configure the controller in two different modes (0 and 1), and uses the same command to to read several bytes from the device. The read results are the same! I also capture the signal with a logic analyser, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: The bottom line is the timing has to work regardless ofthe mode. Don’t get too tied up on the semantics.